# Can a non-shared VPC communicate with a shared VPC direct connect on-prem network?

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, amazon-vpc, aws-direct-connect

Assuming I have two VPCs

- **VPC-A** (non shared, peered with **VPC-B**)
- **VPC-B** (a shared VPC which is configured with direct connect with on prem network)

If I have a VPC endpoint/interface for API Gateway Private RestAPI within **VPC-A**, can an on-prem network communicate with that private VPC endpoint if **VPC-A** is peered with **VPC-B**, since **VPC-B** is connected to on prem via direct connect?

Assuming this is for environment with ~50 Accounts.

Besides **VPC-B** being peered with **VPC-A**, what other configurations need to be made to **VPC-B**? What is the best way to used shared VPCs and how best to organize direct connect connections when shared VPC already has direct connect?

Comment: In the "cross-VPC management" topic

Answer (score 0):

> If you are using VPC peering, on-premises connectivity (VPN and/or Direct Connect)
> must be made to each VPC. Resources in a VPC cannot reach on-premises using the
> hybrid connectivity of a peered VPC (Figure 2).

https://d1.awsstatic.com/whitepapers/building-a-scalable-and-secure-multi-vpc-aws-network-infrastructure.pdf

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]